# Cookies will not execute a prompt and alert through a javascript command

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, alert

I have been trying to make a login page. It checks if there is already a cookie for the username, if so it asks for login details. Otherwise it goes through register procedure. However, this does not work. It just makes the code appear on the console. My full code is on github on the link https://github.com/TheNumnut/Wars-of-Shares/blob/master/Login/index.html
A portion of my code which I think is not working is:

```
function checkCookie(checkusername, checkpassword, register) {
  if (getCookie("username") != "") {
    setCookie("username", checkusername, 365);
    setCookie("password", checkpassword, 365);
  }
  else {
    if (checkusername != getCookie("username") {
      alert("Username wrong");
      window.close();
    }
    else {
      if (checkpassword != getCookie("password") {
        alert("Password wrong");
        window.close();
    window.open("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/", "_self");
}

</script> 
</head> 
<body>
var username = prompt("Username: ");
var password = prompt("Password: ");
checkCookie(username, password);
```

Please tell me if there are any problems. The part which is printed to the website is from var username = prompt("Username:"); until checkCookie(username, password);.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `window.close()` will close the current `window` before the rest of the code is executed.

Comment: Yes, when you write JavaScript code inside the body, with no script element around it, it will be displayed rather than executed. If that actually surprises you, I don’t think you should be let anywhere near login functionality yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an extra ) in the following lines

```
if (checkusername != getCookie("username") {
```

and

```
if (checkpassword != getCookie("password") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Your alerts are not showing because you call **"checkCookie(username, password);"** function in html not in javascript. And also some brackets missing.

```
<script>
function checkCookie(checkusername, checkpassword, register) {
   if (getCookie("username") != "") {
        setCookie("username", checkusername, 365);
        setCookie("password", checkpassword, 365);
   }
   else {
       if (checkusername != getCookie("username") ){
           alert("Username wrong");
           window.close();
       }
       else {
           if (checkpassword != getCookie("password")) {
                alert("Password wrong");
                window.close();
                window.open("https://thenumnut.github.io/Wars-of-Shares/", "_self");
           }
       }
    }
}
checkCookie(username, password);
</script>
```